# Where is documentation for the format of the Facebook cookie?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Where is official documentation for the format of the fbsr_ cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the format of the cookie is documented officially.

I believe the closest thing you'll find at this time, officially, is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/.

[Someone filed a bug about this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/155123487929219) just a few days ago.

Comment: And that document isn't even close. It doesn't actually talk about facebook cookie at all; `cookie : true,` shows up in the code examples and that's as close as the documentation gets to even acknowledging its existence! Here's hoping FB takes that documentation bug seriously.

Comment: I have been searching for some documentation about facebook cookie and how to share session between Facebook JS sdk and server. 

All it talks about is fb.login() and fb.logout() - but how does the server know who the user is, or when does he gets signed out etc

Answer (score 1):

I believe the official Facebook documentation is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/). However there seems to be a sparse amount of information on the topic (see [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/155123487929219/?browse=search_4ef1ace74b3103607591567)).